# Creating a Black hole using sprite kit on xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

I am in the process of creating a game that contains a black whole in the middle of the screen. The center of the black hole is going to be the origin of the gravity. So therefore I would like SKNodes that I create (and allow to be affected by gravity) to gravitate, towards the black hole at the center, (instead of down towards the bottom of the screen). Is there anyway to get this to happen? In other words, would it be possible to shut off the default setting which causes all physics nodes to fall downward, and make something else the origin of the gravity? If so hwo would i go about doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a SKPhysicsWorld setting to achieve this. You need to calculate a force based on the position of each node which needs to be 'sucked in' by the black hole, and apply it in the `-update:` method.

Also, in iOS 8, SpriteKit features the [`SKFieldNode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/index.html) class, which seems exactly like what you are searching for.

Comment: Hmm okay. Im kinda confused as to how to go about doing this. Could I hire you, via paypal to maybe help me set this up?